# How to fix 'Unexpected Token' when I work with ESLint?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, eslint

```sh
  26 | 
  27 | class DefaultLayout extends Component {
> 28 |   loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-1 text-center">Loading...</div>;
     |                   ^
```

ESLint is returning a Parsing Error (Unexpected token) for the opening `<div>` tag. What am I missing? Are normal HTML attributes not allowed in JSX? (The div seems to work fine)

I tried fix them with a lot of config to eslint, babel plugins and webpack config. But I cant fix it.

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["warn", { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "react/jsx-curly-newline": ["warn", { "multiline": "consistent", "singleline": "consistent" }],
    "react/state-in-constructor": ["warn", "always"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["warn", {
      "html": "ignore",
      "custom": "enforce",
      "exceptions": ["Image", "img"]
      }],
      "import/no-named-as-default": "off",
      "import/no-named-as-default-member": "off",
      "max-len": ["warn", { "code": 120 }],
      "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true, "packageDir": "./"}],
      "react/destructuring-assignment": [0],
      "react/prop-types": [0],
      "react/no-array-index-key": "warn"
    }
  }
```

Please, can you help me?

Comment: This project was started with CRA (Create-react-app) but I run (eject).

Comment: do you have   parser: 'babel-eslint' in your eslint-config-react-app package? It should be in the index.js file.

Comment: I don't have 'babel-eslint' in my index.js, I have parser": "babel-eslint" in .eslintrc.json

Comment: See if this helps: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing the Prettier extension.